# Why does Excel average gives different result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's the table:

[image]

Should not they have the same result mathematically? (the average score of the per column and per row average)

Comment: Could some rounding be taking place here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, None. No round-offs done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing cells mean that your cells aren't all weighted evenly.

For example, row 11 has only two cells 82.67 and 90. So for your row average for row 11 they are weighted much more heavily than in your column averages where they are 1/13 and 1/14 of a column instead of 1/2 of a row.

Try filling up all the empty cells with 0 and the averages should match.

Taking a more extreme version of Ruslan Karaev's example:

```
5 5 5 | 5
1     | 1  Average of Average of Rows = (5 + 1 + 0) / 3 = 2
0     | 0
-----
2 5 5
Average of Average of Columns = (2 + 5 + 5) / 3 = 4
```

Comment: I was using AVERAGEIF thus ignoring the zeros and empty cells.

Comment: 82.67 is contributing to 1/2 of a row average, that's 1/32 of the overall average. That's much more than a cell in a full row which only contributed 1/11 * 1/16 = 1/176 of the overall average.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  Even though each _row_ or _column_ average ignores empty cells, you are still _weighing_ all rows and columns evenly.  This is flawed logic, resulting in your current output.

Comment: I won't remove my answer since rounding *may* still be an issue. But I think it's clear from your example that this is the most likely answer. Good job (and a vote of course).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example, the following two expressions:

```
 / a + b   X + Y \     / a + X   b + Y \
(  ----- + -----  )   (  ----- + -----  )
 \   2       2   /     \   2       2   /
-------------------   -------------------
         2                     2
```

are *indeed* mathematically equivalent, both coming out to be `(a + b + X + Y) / 4`.

However, short of having enough sufficient precision to store values, you may find that rounding errors accumulate differently depending on the order of operations.

You can see this sort of effect in a much simpler example if you assume a 3-digit precision and divide one by three, then multiply the result of that by three again:

```
1 / 3 -> 0.333, 0.333 x 3 -> 0.999
```

Contrast that with doing the operations in the oppisite order:

```
1 x 3 = 3, 3 / 1 = 1
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense. But I didn't round off the figures.

Comment: @Ronald, *you* may not have rounded off the figures, but it's possible Excel did :-)

Comment: I don't think rounding is the issue here.

Comment: @paxdiablo, thanks for the answer. But I really did not do any rounding-off. It seems that user c's edited answer makes sense.